# How to inject working alert code from a HTML text form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, frontend

I am fairly new coding in JavaScript and web development, and I was wondering if there was any way to input an alert through an HTML text form and have it run on another page after it has been submitted, right now this is what I have.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="results.html" method="GET">
        <div>
            <label>Name</label> <input style="width: 400px;" size=400px type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="username" required>
        </div>
        
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**results.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Results</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="results"></div>
    
    <a href="index.html">Back to Form</a>

    <script>
        const resultsList = document.getElementById('results')
        new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).forEach((value,
        name) => {
             resultsList.append(`${name}: ${value}`)
             resultsList.append(document.createElement('br'))
         })
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to get something like this

My input

[image]

What I am trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: Not without being wide open to XSS

Answer (score 0):

You have to receive a variable that you send with the "get" method.

With the window.location object. This code gives you GET without the question mark.

```
 let myTextAlert =   window.location.search.substr(1)
```

(You can use `split()` method to get rid of &)

Next in Your div or insert js:

```
<div id="results">

<script>
  alert("This page Says:" + myTextAlert); 
</script> 

</div>
```